# Textbook for US Treasury Bond / Notes Futures

Tags: interest-rates, futures, bond-futures, eurodollars, treasuries

Is the text [The Treasury Bond Basis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071456104) by Burghardt still the authoritative source on this topic?  The most recent edition was published in 2005.  I think that, based on the contents and others' referrals, the text will be a very useful introduction, but I also imagine some of the material is out-of-date and some topics currently viewed as important not included.  Is there a more recent recommendable text available to supplement this one or outright replace it?  Or perhaps better yet, a set of supplementary lecture notes for a course where this text was used?

I'm similarly curious about [The Eurodollar Futures and Options Handbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071418555).

I'm moving to a liquid rates desk in the near future (quant role), and I need to be up-to-date on these products/markets.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit like reading Hull with his WSJ corn futures prices printouts. I liked this one better: https://www.amazon.com/Interest-Rate-Markets-Practical-Approach/dp/0470932201/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1484839932&sr=1-1&keywords=interest+rates

Comment: I think Burghardt is still considered the reference on bond futures.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is no better reference than *The Treasury Bond Basis*, which I still read cover-to-cover at least once a year.

Since the publication of the 2005 edition, the biggest development is the introduction of the WN (ultra-long bond) contract in 2009. The TN (ultra 10-year) contract was introduced in 2016 as well. But the same set of tools and analytical techniques would apply.

As @LazyCat mentioned, *Interest Rate Markets* is also a great reference. The discussion on futures calendar spread is particularly good, but Burghardt's *Bond Basis* still provides extensive/unrivaled historical context for understanding the evolution of bond basis.